# Does Idris have an equivalent of hackage or pursuit?

Tags: idris

That is, does there yet exist a central package repository of open source software written in Idris?

Some googling led me to the idris-hackers github page, [here](http://idris-hackers.github.io). And I can also search for projects on github written in Idris, of course. I was basically wondering if there is another well known site I am missing to look for Idris packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is not really a central package set for Idris yet.

But [it looks like](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Contributions-Needed) it has high priority.

The closest i could find [is in](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/development/idris-modules) Nix. Though probably in very infant state.